# map a valid email adress to localhost user

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-server

I developp locally (ubuntu 15.04 with LAMP) websites and I need to test that a website is really sending emails. I cannot figure out if it is possible to say that if the email is toto@toto.com, the mail server is sending it to user@localhost.

I followed http://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/ and I can send email from user@localhost to user@localhost.

If you need more information, just ask. If my question has been answered, it is because I miss the vocabulary to make the correct search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are running with the default postfix configuration.
Configuring postfix for with domain mappings like here http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html
then user mappings like here
http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

The default may also work if you reconfigure postfix to match your domain with `dpkg-reconfigure`
This should be a comment but couldnt post one.

Comment: thanks for your help, I had a look at these links but cannot understand if I can have "Postfix virtual ALIAS example: separate domains, UNIX system accounts" with a domain that is not managed on my localhost. e.g. : everytime I send mail to toto@toto.com, the mail server deals with it locally without having to reach toto.com on the internet. is that correct ?

Comment: My understanding/experience of it would be that when the domain mappings are in effect ,mail destined for either localhost or toto.com should deliver to local users... as you mentioned you wanted toto to deliver to user i also inclided the link for rewriting users... otherwise i would expect user@toto.com to be deliverable.